# Using a .bat file with TeXlipse

Tags: compiling, texlipse, eclipse

I use TeXlipse as editor of my choice.

Since I use the `nomencl` package, I added a `.bat` file in TeXlipse preferences:

```
@echo off

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
makeindex main.idx
makeindex main.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o main.nls
bibtex main
```

Now my problem is that every project would use this `.bat` file in this folder. If I have to swap between two projects I always need to adapt the file.

Is there a way I can specify a `.bat` file directly in the `.tex` file, so that I can use a `.bat` file for a specific project?

Comment: Is not possible to use a kind of variable to the main file? Something like %f.tex?

Answer (score 5):

You have a different option now: just add

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: makeindex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
```

at the beginning of your LaTeX file (say `main.tex`) and change the `.bat` file into

```
@echo off

arara main
```

If you have an uptodate TeX Live 2012, arara will already be available. With MiKTeX 2.9 you have to install it. See https://github.com/cereda/arara for finding the installer and the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In the builder of Texlipse you can call your .bat as usual and in the arguments pour `%input`.

[image]

Then in your .bat you can do

```
@echo off
cd "%~dp1"
set texSource=%~n1

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%texSource%.tex"
makeindex %texSource%.idx
makeindex %texSource%.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %texSource%.nls
bibtex %texSource%
```

Also, I suggest you look at using LatexMK which, after you installed Perl, allows you to replace all that above with

```
latexmk -pdflatex="pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1" -pdf "%texSource%" -r latexmk
```

for instance.