# How to provide a Makefile to Texlipse?

Tags: texlipse, makefile, build-system

gurus,

The question can probably be formulated in a couple of ways. When I created my Latex project in Texlipse, I told Eclipse to put all PDFs in the *out* folder, and all sources including my *main.tex* file in the *src* folder. All temporary files are stored in *tmp*.

However, Texlipse complains about page numbering (let us skip the exact problem here) which are solved by running pdflatex, bibtex and then pdflatex again three times:

The following Makefile generates a well-formed PDF with good page numbering.

```
all: pdf

pdf:
    pdflatex main
    bibtex main
    pdflatex main
    pdflatex main
    pdflatex main
```

I would like Texlipse to automatically do the building in that sequence to properly generate my PDF. I couldn't figure out how to configure Texlipse's *Builder* to do this.

Lastly, on a side note, although I do not want to use the *Makefile* all the time, I would nevertheless want my Makefile to be in the root folder where *src*, *out*, *tmp* are located. I want to configure the options for pdflatex to find all the sources in *src*, and output the PDF in *out* and put all temporary files in *tmp*. How can I do that? That said, if I have a proper Makefile that does the job neatly and cleanly, how can I just tell Texlipse to use that Makefile when I want it to *Build Automatically*?

Many thanks for the support.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara). It's not exactly what you're after, but you might find it equally useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LatexMK and call it from a .bat file that is located in your project root.

Eclipse still takes care of cleaning up the tmp after the build is finished.

See my post here on how to do this either using your makefile or using latexmk.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173268/6908